# What is my output and input tensor names?

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, model, tensorboard

I've tried a lot of things to find the input and output tensor names. I first tried the following block of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
frozen='C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
gf = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
gf.ParseFromString(open(frozen,'rb').read())
[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ( 'Softmax','Placeholder')]    
[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ( 'Softmax','Mul')]
```

Something like this:

[image: output1][image: output2]

Then I tried to look at the tensorboard chart:

[image: tensorboard]

But it was very complicated and I couldn't figure it out. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the function below in order to get the names.

**tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name()**